# I've setup Monero Core Gui 0.11.0.0 on my old laptop with location to E:Drive for blockchain. How to move to new laptop

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod

I've everything running fine on old laptop with Monero v 0.11.0. Now I try to move this (Monero GUI Folder, blockchain folder and Keys) to new laptop.
And try to restore from keys, I can see it is showing my balance correctly. Now while starting Daemon with fails and I try to do it from cmd line and it fails

```
E:\monero-gui-win-x64-v0.11.0.0\monero-gui-0.11.0.0>monerod --data-dir E:\MoneroBlockchain\
2018-02-27 17:17:35.875 9824    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:279 Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.0.0-release)
2018-02-27 17:17:35.875 9824    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:55        Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2018-02-27 17:17:35.876 9824    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:60        Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2018-02-27 17:17:35.877 9824    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63     Initializing p2p server...
2018-02-27 17:17:37.119 9824    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:68     P2p server initialized OK
2018-02-27 17:17:37.120 9824    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:58     Initializing core rpc server...
2018-02-27 17:17:37.124 9824    INFO    global  contrib/epee/include/net/http_server_impl_base.h:70  Binding on 127.0.0.1:18081
2018-02-27 17:17:37.125 9824    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:63     Core rpc server initialized OK on port: 18081
2018-02-27 17:17:37.126 9824    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:73    Initializing core...
2018-02-27 17:17:37.127 9824    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:323     Loading blockchain from folder E:\MoneroBlockchain\lmdb ...
2018-02-27 17:17:37.374 9824    ERROR   cn      src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:102 Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-02-27 17:17:37.375 9824    ERROR   txpool  src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp:1020    Failed to parse tx from txpool
2018-02-27 17:17:37.375 9824    ERROR   cn      src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:409     Failed to initialize memory pool
2018-02-27 17:17:37.376 9824    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:90     Deinitializing rpc server...
```

May be something corrupted.
What is right way to Move Wallet with blockchain db file to new laptop?

Comment: try adding `--drop-txpool` to your command line options

Answer (score 1):

Before copying over the files of the Monero blockchain, make sure the daemon is no longer running. Perform a `monerod exit` from a Command Prompt if necessary.

Then, you should copy over the entire directory, in your case `E:\MoneroBlockchain` to the target computer. On the target computer, I would just **remove those `.bin` files**, before starting the daemon. This way, the daemon will rediscover th proper state.

> **Note:** Monero 0.11.0 isn't the lastest version, you should probably use **0.11.1.0** on the target machine.

The wallet files can just be copied as is. This should work the same on the target computer, but again, try to use the latest version of the software. And always keep a copy of your mnemonic away from the computer. That guarantees you'll always be able to recover your funds.